# Dynamic 2D structure for C#

Tags: c#, dynamic-data

I'm working on a class that is storing a 2D array of class `MyType` and would like it to use dynamic data types. i.e. not `MyType[,]`

The problem with `MyType[,]` is that the class doesn't know the size of the array ahead of time, and I don't want to go to the trouble of managing array re-sizing if it's been done elsewhere in the .NET Frameworks.

The class will not know maximum array size at any given moment, but the array will be dense. I know I can use static arrays, and re-allocate memory as needed, but I'd prefer to use a built-in implementation if possible.

Is there anything better than `List<List<MyType>>` for this purpose?

Edit 1: specified that array is dense;

Edit 2 and 3: specified problem with `MyType[,]`

Comment: It would help to define "better" :)

Comment: better as in more suitable to my needs. I want a sensible balance between performance and not-reinventing-the-wheel. Thanks.

Comment: Re edit 2: no, you didn't. You said "not MyType[,]", but you didn't say *why*. If you tell us the problem, we'll have more chance of fixing it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your own `List<List<T>>` encapsulation like :

```
public class Matrix<T>
{
   List<List<T>> matrix;

   public void Add(IEnumerable<T> row)
   {
      List<T> newRow = new List<T>(row);
      matrix.Add(newRow);
   }

   public T this[int x, int y]
   {
      get  { return matrix[y][x]; }
   }
   ....
}
```

define your own set of operation on it ! Be freee !

**By encapsulating it, you can decide to go for a more optimised implementation later if it's not sufficient.**

```
        ICollection<T> rowOne = (ICollection<T>)new List<Int64>();
        rowOne.Add(1);
        rowOneList.Add(2);
        rowOne.Add(3);

        ICollection<T> rowTwo = (ICollection<T>)new List<Int64>();
        rowTwo .Add(4);
        rowTwo .Add(5);
        rowTwo .Add(6);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how sparse your structure will be. For instance, if your entries will resemble something like `myTypes[0, 1]` and `myTypes[134, 544]`, you'd be much better off using [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix). Otherwise, `List<List<MyType>>` will do.

Answer (score 1):

For a dense 2D matrix, a rectangular array is ideal. What is the issue you are having with `SomeType[,]`? Note that you can create dynamic arrays either with `Array.CreateInstance(type, dim0Size, dim1Size)`, or with generics:

```
void DoWork<T>(...) {
   T[,] data = ...
}
DoWork<Foo>(...);
DoWork<Bar>(...);
```

(perhaps using `MakeGenericMethod` if you want to use ad-hoc types)